# integration Buttons in Dialogflow Web demo Chatbot

Tags: web, button, dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot

i have a question about chatbots with dialogflow.
I am currently building a chatbot in Dialogflow. I would like to add this chatbot to my website. My problem is that this chatbot should also contain buttons, that the user can click on this. I have built some buttons,but I can't see the buttons in the Dialogflow web demo. There are buttons on dialogflow console, but it isn't shown on the web demo. Does anyone know what that could be?
I only found it as a source kommunicate.io, which didn't really help me either.

Thanks for answers..

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow Web Demo does not support rich responses (buttons, cards, images etc..). For integrating it to your webpage you can either use third-party solutions like Kommunicate or build your own web wedge.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, DialogFlow web demo does not provide rich responses like the card, quick replies & suggestion chips. But you can use Dialog Flow messenger(New Feature) to add buttons & images. You've to use Custom Payload for getting a rich response.